# How to call multiple instances of the same child component's function from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I know that using ref's I can call a function in a child component from the parent component. But my problem is I'm having multiple instances of the child component and I need to invoke the same function in all the children components.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useRef, useImperativeHandle, useEffect} = React;

const Parent = ({title}) => {

  const childRef1 = useRef();
  const childRef2 = useRef();
  const childRef3 = useRef();
  const childRef4 = useRef();
  const childRef5 = useRef();
  const handleClick = () => {
  
    childRef1.current.increment()
    childRef2.current.increment()
    childRef3.current.increment()
    childRef4.current.increment()
    childRef5.current.increment()
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <Child num={1} childRef={childRef1} />
      <Child num={2} childRef={childRef2} />
      <Child num={3} childRef={childRef3} />
      <Child num={4} childRef={childRef4} />
      <Child num={5} childRef={childRef5} />
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({num, childRef}) => {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  useImperativeHandle(childRef, () => ({
    increment() {
      // if(textEditable)
      setCount(count+1)
    },
  }));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(num)
  }, [num])
  
  return (
    <div>
    {
      count
    }
    </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

My question is how should I do the same if I'm rendering the child components inside a map function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that using ref's I can call a function...

Perfect!  In that case, we will use the same procedure, but simply expand it a bit further.

Set either the component or the state to hold the child components...

```
this.state.children = [];
```

Then `map()` them like so...

```
var children = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
children.map((child) => {
    return (
        <Child
            num={child}
            ref={(instance) => {this.state.children[child] = instance}}
        />
    );
});
```

Then call the functions on with a `forEach()` on them...

```
Object.keys(this.state.children).forEach((child) => {
    var childinstance = this.state.children[child];
    childinstance.specialFunction();
});
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, this is almost never the ideal solution. Restructuring the components to not require the parent to hold an unknown number of refs is probably more ideal

Answer (score 1):

I did it with hooks like below.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useRef, useImperativeHandle, useEffect} = React;

const Parent = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [children, setChildren] = useState(5);
  
  const [childRefs, setChildRefs] = useState([])
  
  const handleClick = () => childRefs.forEach(c => c.current.increment())
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    setChildRefs([...Array(children).keys()].map(e => React.createRef()))
  }, [title])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      {
        [...Array(children).keys()].map(e => <Child
            num={e}
            childRef={ childRefs[e] }
        />)
      }
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({num, childRef}) => {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  useImperativeHandle(childRef, () => ({
    increment() {
      // if(textEditable)
      setCount(count+1)
    },
  }));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(num)
  }, [num])
  
  return (
    <div>
    {
      count
    }
    </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Track the state in the parent and pass it to the child as a prop:

```
const Parent = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <Child count={count} />
      <Child count={count} />
      <Child count={count} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you need them to be independent, use an array for the state:

```
const Parent = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([0,1,42,96]);

  const onIncrement = index => {
    // probably a better way to do this. just here for illustrative purposes
    const newCount = [...count];
    newCount.splice(index, 1, count[index] + 1);
    setCount(newCount);
  }

  const incrementAll = () => setCount(count.map(x => x + 1));

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      { count.map((entry, index) => (
        <Child
          num={entry}
          key={index}
          onIncrement={() => onIncrement(index))} {/* if you want the child to be able to do it */}
        />
      )) }
      <button onClick={incrementAll}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```